# Manager just threatened the entire team for a problem that she doesn't fully understand. What to do?

Tags: manager, performance-reviews

About a year ago I moved to a new team that wasn't in great shape. The old members were not really doing their jobs very well, and many people got fired to make room for people who would. This specific incident involves customer relationship management (CRM). Basically, whenever we work with a client we have to note certain things, especially any concerns we have about the client relationship moving forward so that they can be addressed.

It is true that some members of the current team don't log this information well, and it looks like their clients are all perfectly happy when in fact there may be issues that aren't getting logged. On the other hand, some members of the team, either because they got easy clients, easy projects, or are just good at what they do, really don't have that many client concerns.

The problem is the aggregate data groups both of these employees into one - "your number of client concerns is nearly zero" - and the manager considers them to be the same.

The manager took us into a meeting (there are about 20 of us) and talked about how the resulting high customer satisfaction numbers make it look like we aren't doing our jobs. She told us that if this continues it will affect our bonuses, and that some of us have more to worry about than others.

If I were in her situation, I would not have done this publicly, and I would have first tried to understand each person's CRM reports with that person first, then coached them through it. Her response was enough to make me start looking for another job, but in the event that doesn't work out, how do I proceed? From my perspective, I think a lot of team members (if they don't just leave) are going to start faking CRM reports...

Comment: "about how such high numbers make it look like we aren't doing our jobs" You mean "low numbers"?

Comment: Well... High satisfaction numbers, low reports of dissatisfaction. However it makes sense

Comment: Ah, the classic of using a (useless) number to lazily measure  performance and finding out that people will optimize that number in many different ways...

Comment: @work572: That's an important clarification. I edited it into your Q.

Comment: @Anketam yes it is

Comment: Telling a CRM person "All your clients are happy, you aren't doing your job" is kinda like telling a security guard "Nothing got stolen all week, what are you even doing here"...

Comment: The team members that don't log the information: are they at least fixing the client concerns, leaving the relationship in a good state, or are they ignoring them endangering the relationship?

Comment: @Erik That's just classic IT benchmarking. If nothing is happening, why do they need IT? If everything is broken, what is IT doing? There is no metric for a "good" IT team because a good team looks like they're doing nothing since all the problems got prevented instead of a fire being put out. Nobody has yet figured out how to measure effective preventative actions.

Comment: @Rup I tink it's totally random. If I'm going to guess, we have MAYBE one person on the team who really is just logging "everything's great" reports all the time. Otherwise, many times the clients are really just happy with what we did - they asked for X, we did X. I believe what sparked this is that a client complained and the manager noticed that  the CRM reports were all peachy for that client, so she pulled all the reports and noticed that many clients don't have any issues reported...

Comment: "the resulting high customer satisfaction numbers make it look like we aren't doing our jobs". The only solution I see is to make customers less satisfied. Are you hiring? :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've been in this situation many times. I just log everything conscientiously and don't care what others do. Then if there's any queries I just pull up my time tracking log and hand it in. Usually it's just people being too lazy to do the record keeping properly.

This is the best protection possible and should be mandatory for any client facing interactions. It makes you bullet proof both from internal and external issues as you have a formal running record to refer to and complainers usually have zilch.

I've had whole teams sacked or disciplined around me while I just quietly keep working. Proper record keeping will rip both clients and managers a new orifice if there are disputes.

Answer (score 11):

My response would be a calm note to my second line manager pointing out that there seems to be a misunderstanding here and some bad management practice, as you've described it to us, and asking that they give my direct manager a bit of guidance before things get out of control.

I might add that I feel concerned enough that I'd be seriously interested in transferring to an adjacent department, if there's one that can use me. (You don't always need to leave the company to find a new job.)

Comment: +1 for proactive escalation and being direct about this!

Answer (score 4):

It sounds like this was poorly handled, and you're annoyed about it, but I think you have the solution already: she needs to

> understand each person's CRM reports with that person first, then coach them through it

Why not volunteer? I assume you're in the second category and your customers genuinely don't have many concerns. Invite her along to your next face-to-face meeting with a client so she can see for herself. Talk her through your other clients too, and convince her your high scores are genuine. Ask her for suggestions what more you can do, and how you can get more out of your happy clients.

Comment: I do like the idea, but I'm afraid that this is enabling. Here, I feel that her threatening us was out of line, so inviting her to see so I can prove something that isn't a problem is something I'm a bit iffy on. What do you think?

Comment: You're probably right. I guess I misjudged it and was more thinking about "how to fix my situation" rather than "how to fix the manager".

Answer (score 1):

I don't think your managers request is that unreasonable. Look at it from her POV. Unless someone is actively losing clients/sales/etcetera it's impossible for your tell there are no concerns or if you just aren't seeing them.

Also, just because the client doesn't have any concerns doesn't mean you shouldn't have any.

Say you are in sales and you have a client who is 100% completely satisfied, your concern could be selling them more/different products.

If you are afraid doing so might be viewed as pushy and will alienate a good client, be concerned about if offering them more/different products would potentially alienate a good client and discuss with the manager whether it is worth the risk.

Yes lots of these concerns might be B.S. but even if just 1/10 are fruitful and sells more or causes you to have a better relationship with a customer it will be worth it to the company.